# Как сделать игру HTML

Tags: html, html5

С помощью каких тегов можно сделать игру HTML без javascript?

Comment: с помощью java


Comment: <game>...</game>. А если серьезно, HTML - это язык разметки. На нем даже 1+2 вычислить не получится.

Comment: Пожалуй, 1+2 (и вообще любую операцию сложения натуральных чисел) осуществить как раз можно: берете 1 <li>, берете еще 2 <li>, ставите их рядом в <ol> и смотрите на число в последнем пункте списка :) Но на этом, похоже, все и закончится.

Comment: @yozh да, я представляю, как тогда вычисляется сумма вроде 9131+214131 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можете сделать игру-лабиринт. Для этого потребуются теги html, head, title, body, p и a. И много-много страничек. И куча текста.

Comment: +1. Или вот как на википедии - кто быстрее доберется с одной страницы на другую. Или квест какой-нибудь: "вы стоите на перекрестке..." - в принципе тот же лабиринт.

Answer (score 3):

1. делаете игру на html
2. ???
3. PROFIT!

Answer (score 0):

На HTML без скриптов содержательную игру сделать нереально. Максимум, что может получиться, это красивые анимации, при движении мышью по экрану. Посмотреть на возможности можно здесь: [CSS3](http://slides.html5rocks.com/#css3-title).

Comment: [Посоны с LtU говорят](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/4222) что HTML5+CSS3 (без всякого JS) Тьюринг-полны, так что, при очень большом желании, можно сделать все что угодно. Но для этого надо знать толк в извращениях.

Comment: Крутая тема! :) Только непонятно, что они имеют в виду под HTML5, только ли разметку или что еще.